# Alert notification issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have setup outgoing email settings in Central Admin but

I am only getting the initial subscription alert for sharepoint list

not getting any email on any further changes

let me know the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are adding/modifying the list items by logging in as system account. Can you try by logging in as any other user and see if the alerts are coming up.

Answer (score 0):

this is a great place to start, I would post all the steps but its too big so only posting the link, this should solve your issue stage by stage :)

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-checklist.html

hope it helps :)